# Solve for x negative exponential

Tags: exponential-function, substitution

I have the following equation:

$y = 14857x^{-1.092}$

I know $y = 43$, how do I rewrite this to solve for $x$.

e.g. $43 = 14857x^{-1.092}$

Comment: $x = (\frac{14857}{y})^{\frac{1}{1.092}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have $$43 = 14857x^{-1.092}$$
write it as $$x^{-1.092}=\frac{1}{x^{1.092}}=\frac{43}{14857}$$
You get $$x^{1.092}=\frac{14857}{43}$$
Divide for the power $1.092$: $$x=(\frac{14857}{43})^{\frac{1}{1.092}}=211.154$$